# Get all possible partitions of number

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Is there a way to get all possible partitions of an integer? Possibly specifying max and/or min summand. I'm interested in partitions themselves, not just partition count.

Comment: You can do an algorithm, if you are patient, but there isn't (known) any formula to compute it. It's interesting that for the first integers you get prime numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning

Comment: @Diego, an algorithm is a formula is an  algorithm, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson By formula I mean an elementary function known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Perl:

```
sub partition {
  print "@_\n";
  my ($largest, @rest) = @_;
  my $min = $rest[0] || 1;
  my $max  = int($largest/2);
  for my $n ($min .. $max) {
    partition($largest-$n, $n, @rest);
  }
}
```

The code should be easy to translate into other languages, once you know that `@_` is Perl's notation for the list of arguments to a function.  To invoke, use something like

```
partition(6)
```

which will produce the output

```
6
5 1
4 1 1
3 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
3 2 1
4 2  
2 2 2
3 3
```

Simple tinkering with the function will produce the outputs in other orders, possibly more useful.

[Chapter 5 of *Higher-Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/05FromRecursionToIterators.pdf) has an extensive discussion of this function.

---

Here it is in Python:

```
def partition(largest, *rest):
    print(largest, *rest)
    min = rest[0] if rest else 1
    max = largest // 2
    for n in range(min, max+1):
        partition(largest-n, n, *rest)
```

Answer (score 4):

The book
"Combinatorial Algorithms. For Computers and Calculators. Second Edition"
by ALBERT NIJENHUIS and HERBERT S. WILF
is available in pdf at
http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombinatorialAlgorithms.pdf
.
It has algorithms for many combinatorial computations
including generating all partitions of an integer.

Lots of good stuff here,
but beware the sometimes hard to understand
fortran.
Its heapsort routine does it in 22 lines of
non-recursive fortran.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like worth to take a look!